# Installing Boost in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, gcc, boost

I recently set up an AWS EC2 Linux instance, and I'm trying to install boost using the following code:

```
wget -c 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.66.0/boost_1_66_0.tar.bz2
tar jxf boost_1_66_0.tar.bz2
cd boost_1_66_0
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: no command provided, default command 'g++' not found
error: initialized from project-config.jam:12
```

Also, when I tried installing g++, which I thought I had already done by issuing this:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

The result:

```
Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-1.22.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: run `sudo yum install gcc-c++` if using amazon AMI or `sudo apt-get install g++` if on ubuntu'

Comment: Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-1.22.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: What do you get by running the command `g++`

Comment: g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: @iamcaleberic usually, `build-essential` which includes other... essentials for building. @ OP: You have to install the requirements

Comment: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html

Comment: it seems like the build system can't find your compiler and/or linker, consider setting up a user-config.jam file as described here. the above link

Comment: @sehe This should be answer actually. With these tools 1) it works and 2) you have the guarantee that what you'll do will be compatible with managed services such as Lambda

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing other build tools required for compiling. Installing following should fix your problem,

```
sudo yum install -y gcc libxml2-devel gcc-c++ make
```

You can uninstall the tools afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

On AWS Linux the way to go is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html

Or execute command:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

This should help.